# Unable to create NSData in Swift?

Tags: syntax, swift2

Pray tell, what is wrong with this?

```
let indices: [UInt8] = [ 0, 2, 1 ]
let indexData: NSData = NSData(bytes:indices as UInt8, length: sizeof(indices))
```

I'm using Xcode 7(Beta)/Swift 2.0

Continually running into:
Cannot find an initializer  for type 'NSData' that accepts and argument list of type '(bytes:int, length:int)'

Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would go back and forth between a byte array and NSData.

```
// Works in a playground as is

// Convert [UInt8] to NSData
let indices: [UInt8] = [ 0, 2, 1 ]
let indexData: NSData = NSData(bytes:indices, length: indices.count)

// Get [UInt8] from NSData
var bytes = [UInt8](count: indexData.length, repeatedValue: 0)
indexData.getBytes(&bytes, length: indexData.length)
print(bytes)
```